# execute script whenever I open the git bash

Tags: bash, git, intellij-idea, ssh, terminal

Alright, so I have bitbucket set up with an SSH key.

I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate on Windows 10 (but the solution to the question doesn't need to be IntelliJ-intern, so please read on).

I quite like the bash terminal and would like to switch out the useless cmd that is  inserted by default for the git terminal.

So I go to
`File -> Other Settings -> Settings for new Projects -> Tools -> Terminal`
and set it to `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe`

Works fine ... EXCEPT it asks me for the ssh passphrase every single time I do anything ssh.

So let's do

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

That solves the problem ... temporarily.

Close the terminal and reopen it and you're going to have to enter your passphrase again.

Is there a way I can define a script or something that automatically executes

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

every time I open a new terminal (in that terminal)?

As I mentioned in the beginning, this doesn't have to be an IntelliJ-intern solution, I'm perfectly fine with executing this every time I open the git bash in IntelliJ *or* on its own.

Comment: I think you have cloned your project by https address. If you clone it by ssh address (or set remote url of your project to ssh address) probably git never ask username/password again.

Comment: @MortezaZiaeemehr it's not asking for the bitbucket "username/password", it's asking for the ssh key passphrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get to whatever bash considers your home directory by executing `cd` with no arguments
you can create a `.bashrc` file if one doesn't already exist and add

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

to it.

Comment: you can do this in a `.bashrc` but it will complain about an invalid setup and create a `.bash_profile` that calls the `.bashrc` you wrote

Comment: actually ... I tried both, now, and the `.bash_profile` one doesn't work.

Comment: Oh strange. Did you get the message that a `.bash_profile` calling the `.bashrc` file you had created was generated after you made the `.bashrc` file?

Comment: No, both files already were created. The `.bash_profile` contained three lines : `# generated by Git for Windows`,
`test -f ~/.profile && . ~/.profile` and 
`test -f ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc`
and the `.bashrc` contained only one line: `source "/c/Program Files/git-subrepo/.rc"`.

Comment: oh interesting. Maybe intellij did some setup for you? In any case it seems `.bashrc` works in both cases, will update my answer

Comment: I think it was the git setup, rather than IntelliJ. But who knows.